# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain in node js application

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, self-signed-certificate

I work for a company that has strict IT policy. I work behind a proxy and i mostly use Proxifier or sometimes set proxy in Windows setting. 
I am developing API with Node.js and at first just to test I created a simple route that makes a call to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'. Whenever I test my route in Postman, I get error "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain" in command prompt where node js is running. 
But when I test 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' directly in Postman, it works. 
**here is the simple code I wrote to test**:

```
exports.testing = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        console.log({"Data": data.data})
    }catch(err){
        console.error({"ERROR": err});
    }
}
```

**What I have tried**:
npm config set strict-ssl false --global (didn't help, i assume this is for downloading npm packages)
npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem --global (didn't help)
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 (didn't help)
set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/your/cert.pem (didn't help)

P.S.
When I use mobile data, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
})
```

Not a perfect solution, but ok for development env

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).